# Android: How to validate a set of fields without using TextWatcher and TextChangeListener

Tags: android, validation

I have a number of EditText in an Activity. On clicking the submit button, I want to validate them, and prevent submission if there are errors in those EditText objects. I don't want to use TextWatcher because I don't want the methods to get fired at every single change. It does not make sense for an overall validation before submission. Is there a method that lets us loop through an array of the controls of the form? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, taking ideas from Lucas, creating custom components such as a DateEditText extending EditText and implementing a Validator interface, in my activity button for update onclick, I call this method that I wrote "isValidViewGroup(ViewGroup viewGroup), it will recursively go through all views, starting with the given viewGroup, and check children views, until it meets one implementing Validator and then call its isValid() method. It stops as soon as it finds an invalid one, or go through the end of views. Here's the method:
...

```
private boolean isValidViewGroup(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    int viewGroupChildCount =  viewGroup.getChildCount();
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0;  i < viewGroupChildCount;i++) {
        view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup){
            if (!isValidViewGroup((ViewGroup) view)){
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if (view instanceof Validator){
                if (!((Validator)view).isValid()){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

...
I'm sure there could be a better, more efficient way, but for the moment that works really fine.

Comment: There is a better way, I'll put up my code later today when I'm free

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1) Create a Utils class with static methods for ensuring that the fields are valid.

i.e. toy example for checking email

```
public class Utils{

    public static boolean isValidEmail(String str){
        return str.contains("@");
    }
}
```

and do so for checking the various fields (phone #, email, name, etc...). In your Activity that has the EditText(s), when you try to submit them, have something like:

```
public boolean validateFields(){
    boolean result = true;
    if(!Utils.isValidEmail(mEmailEdit.getText().toString()){
        mEmailEdit.setError("Invalid email!");
        result = false;
    }
    if(!Utils.isValidName(mEmailEdit.getText().toString()){
        mNameEdit.setError("Invalid name!");
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This is a very simple idea of what you would do. Call validateFields() when clicking the submit button, and if the validateFields() method returns false, then do not proceed with the fields. If it returns true, well then all fields are valid and call another method to submit the data to w/e you are using it for.

2) (Best option for larger projects) Create an interface, call it Validator with a boolean-return function called validate(). This validator interface is extended for each various validation you wish to do, and you create a new interface like so:

```
public interface Validator{
    public boolean validate(String s);
}

public interface EmailValidator extends Validator{
    @Override
    public boolean validate(String s){
        return s.contains("@");
    }
}
```

And extend a new EditText class view that has a Validator interface field, with a getter/setter. Then, in the validateFields() method, we do the same thing except call each EditText's validation interface's validate() method. There are a few more subtleties for this and I can type this all out if interested on how to do exactly. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Of course, this was a simple answer for a proof-of-concept, not the exact validation :P I have no idea what he wants to validate, so didn't want to write the regexp for it

Comment: Thanks, a lot of good advises here. That will definitely help for reusing the custom components. Any idea of an "automatic" way of going through them all and calling the validation on each components that implement/extend Validator? I didn't find anything in the Android documentation that returns a list of a window's child components...

Comment: Right, so in order to validate every component in the window that is an EditText for example? Well, that doesn't exist as-is, but you could most definitely create this. You could be rather creative and create a custom LinearLayout that maps each EditText in it's children, and call a method that validates them all when you need to. Simplifies the process to one call

Comment: I think I will make this today, call it a FormView, and provide the code later, sounds fun.

Comment: Very good suggestion! Actually, one might think to make a custom version of the views he is working with to add the functionalities that aren't yet available in Android. I used to do that with Visual dBASE ... ;-)

Comment: I actually have a number of custom views I'm working on now that do just that :) I find all the time things I want to accomplish with views, that don't exist. It's not that you can't them otherwise, but it should be simplified and cleaner

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way to do this is to get references to each of your sub views after you create the main view via setContentView(..). Use findViewById() to get references to each of them.

Then in your submit button click handler grab the inputs from each of them via something like nameField.getText() and do whatever validation you want. And if it fails show the error to the user in some fashion.

Comment: Thanks w.donahue. I thought there would have been already some kind of method that would have return a list of all of a "window" components" and then go through it, checking, as you suggested for the ones we want to perform validation on. Better yet, as proposed by Lucas above, have the components use a custom "validation" method. I would definitely have given you points as providing part of the solution, but I am not authorized yet! Have a great day!